# image uploading in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>

<body>

   <form name="Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

         Filename: <INPUT type="file" id="submit">

         <INPUT type="button" id="send" value="Upload">

    </form>

    <div id="div" align="center" style="height: 200px;width: 500px;border-style: ridge;border-color: red"></div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">



var img_id=0

var image = new Array()

document.getElementById('send').onclick=function()

{

    img_id++

    var id="imgid"+img_id

    image = document.getElementById('submit').value;

    document.getElementById('div').innerHTML="<img id='"+id+"' src='"+image+"' width=500px height=200px>"



}



</script>



</html>
```

problem with this code is that it's only working in IE not in other browser(firefox,chrome,....etc)
Thanks in advance.

Edit:(updated my post in response to Naren, Bitslitter's) Guys, here the text to add to the discussion posted below:

Thanks guys for the feedback, Naren and Bitslitter's feedback was definitely enlightening.

Would you please recommend how to go about achieving what I want to do here:

In my web application, there is a button, upon clicking a button, a browser open dialogue box appears asking for a image file, user selects an image, the image opens in the web application. Its important for me to have the browser open the image from the local server, as I want to use the HTML5 canvas tag to read the pixels and then convert those pixels into SVG dynamically (using JS). It all sounds more complicated than it should be.

Web applications like Mugtug's Darkroom (http://mugtug.com/darkroom/) have been able to achieve exactly what I want to.

Comment: It is working in firefox 3.6. What is the error are you getting in these browsers?

Comment: According to code..the image shoud be displayed in the div ..but there is no image shown in the div...this is only happening in firefox,chrome,safari..but in IE it is showing ...there is no error on the browser.. but the image in div is not visible....

Comment: As a side note, your `<script>` tag should go within the `<body>` tag; just move the `</body>` after the `</script`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I you load the page in Google Chrome, upload an image and hit Ctrl+Shift+J you will see the error message "Not allowed to load local resource" on the Error console. You can do somthing similar in FireFox with Firebug.
IE won't show the local resources unless your internet security level is set to medium. Chrome and FireFox just won't show content from local resources at all.

Answer (score 4):

IE returns file name with local path("c:\documents\image_path\image.ext") in file input.value and other browsers return only file name.

IE assigns the complete local path of image, so it shows image properly. And other browsers add image path as the name of file (only file name, not absolute path) so the image is not available to show.

If you want to show the image in browser you should upload it to server first and render it from server itself.